# CakePHP Ubuntu exporting Excel

Tags: php, excel, cakephp

I have installed a CakePHP 2.x project with PHP 5.6 in DigitalOcean Droplet with Ubuntu 18.04 x64.
I have same project installed on my local computer (Windows 7, which works fine) and DigitalOcean (which is not working yet).
My issue is Exporting Excel in CakePHP.
I am using the following method I am not able to export my file as excel.

```
<?php
    $nombreArchivo = "horasAgendadas.xls";
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel charset=iso-8859-1");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$nombreArchivo);
?>
```

Could you please tell me what installation should be pending for me in order to get exportation excel to works?
I have tried these with no success, after those I have restart apache:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-zip
sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml
apt-get install php5.6-gd
sudo apt-get install libfile-mimeinfo-perl
```

Regards,
Felipe

Comment: https://packagist.org/?query=cakephp%20excel

Comment: @felipe Use PHPExcel plugin